# How to make an enum as a case insensitive file fetching the data from the DB and converting it into java object ? ( serialization/Deserialization)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, enums

I am unable to fetch the data from the Mongo DB when the enum value (one of the fields) is of a different case in the database.

My main class looks like below...

```
public class Test {


   public static void main(String[] args){

   -------
   --------

   Optional<UserAccount> userAccountInfo= userAccountRepo.findById(id);

   -------
   --------

   }

}
```

```
public class UserAccount{

    private String id;  
    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;
    private AccountStatusEnum status;
    private String address;
    
}
```

```
public enum AccountStatusEnum {

    created,
    failed,
    inprogress;
  
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface UserAccountRepo extends MongoRepository<UserAccount, String> {

    Optional<UserAccount> findById(String id);

}
```

Data in the collection/table.

```
{
  "id":"0123",
  "firstName":"Rama",
  "lastName":"Bharath",
   "status":"CREATED",
   "address":"Bengaluru Dist, Karnataka"
}
```

Note: Getting like below

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.test.enums.AccountStatusEnum.CREATED

Added the below property also to ignore the enum cases, but it didn't work.

```
spring.jackson.mapper.accept-case-insensitive-enums=true
```

Expectation: I should be able to retrieve the data from DB, irrespective of cases(upper/lower) in DB.

Comment: Tip: By convention, enum objects in Java are named in ALL UPPERCASE. Abiding this convention would make moot your issue.

Comment: Agree ..@BasilBourque.  It is too old code, right now no option to modify it.